Add Card Button Not Working on iPhone 14 with Latest iOS Version - React Native App
I'm experiencing an issue with the "Add Card" button not responding within a BottomSheetModal on an iPhone 14 running the latest iOS version. The button is visible but does not trigger any actions when pressed.
Here are some details:
Device: iPhone 14
UI Library: Using @gorhom/bottom-sheet for modal behavior
I've checked for possible issues but haven’t found console errors or warnings.
Question
Would there be a known issue with iOS gestures, BottomSheetModal, or iPhone 14 in React Native? Are there additional @gorhom/bottom-sheet configurations that could help resolve this?
Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!
PaymentMethods component:


/* eslint-disable object-curly-newline */
/* eslint-disable no-multiple-empty-lines */
import React, {
  useState,
  useEffect,
  useRef,
  useMemo,
  useCallback,
} from 'react';
import { ScrollView, View } from 'react-native';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { BottomSheetModal, BottomSheetBackdrop } from '@gorhom/bottom-sheet';
import { Text, Card, Button, Layout } from '@ui-kitten/components';
import { PAYMENT_TYPES } from 'utils/constants';
import { t } from 'services/i18n';
import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { fetchPaymentMethods } from 'reducers/paymentMethods';
import { setScreen } from 'utils/handleLogEvent';
import VisaLogo from 'assets/svg/visaLogo';
import MasterCardLogo from 'assets/svg/masterCardLogo';
import Icon from 'components/Icon';
import { resetRedirectData } from 'reducers/vgs';
import AddPaymentMethodBottomSheetContent from 'components/BottomSheet/addPaymentMethodBottomSheetContent';

import styles from './styles';
import { CARD_TYPES } from '../../../utils/constants';

function PaymentMethods({ route, navigation }) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const paymentMethods = useSelector((state) => state.paymentMethods);
  const isFocused = useIsFocused();

  // Do not remove: although not used it triggers re-render on Language change
  const currLang = useSelector((state) => state.language.language);
  const isRTL = currLang === 'ar';

  const [defaultCard, setDefaultCard] = useState([]);

  const [showVgsForm, setShowVgsForm] = useState(true);

  const bottomSheetRef = useRef(null);
  const snapPoints = useMemo(() => ['10%', '75%'], []);

  const showBottomSheetHandler = useCallback(() => {
    bottomSheetRef?.current?.present();
    setShowVgsForm(true);
  }, [bottomSheetRef]);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(resetRedirectData());
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchPaymentMethods());
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setDefaultCard(
      paymentMethods.list.find(
        (pm) => pm.isDefault
          && (pm.pmType === PAYMENT_TYPES.PAYTABS_2
            || pm.pmType === PAYMENT_TYPES.HYPER_PAY
            || pm.pmType === PAYMENT_TYPES.TAP),
      ),
    );
  }, [paymentMethods]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isFocused) {
      setScreen('PaymentMethods');
    }
  }, [isFocused]);

  const renderListItemIcon = (props, item) => {
    if (!item) return null;
    if (item.type) {
      let logo = (
        <Text category="s2">
          {item.type.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() + item.type.slice(1)}
        </Text>
      );
      if (CARD_TYPES.visa.includes(item.type)) {
        logo = <VisaLogo />;
      } else if (CARD_TYPES.mastercard.includes(item.type)) {
        logo = <MasterCardLogo />;
      }
      return <View style={styles.cardLogo}>{logo}</View>;
    }
    return null;
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Layout style={styles.layout}>
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            marginVertical: 5,
          }}
        >
          <ScrollView overScrollMode="never">
            <Card
              status="control"
              style={{
                display: 'flex',
                marginTop: 1,
                borderRadius: 10,
              }}
            >
              {defaultCard ? (
                <View
                  style={{
                    display: 'flex',
                    flexDirection: 'row',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    justifyContent: 'space-between',
                  }}
                >
                  <View
                    style={{
                      display: 'flex',
                      flexDirection: 'column',
                      alignItems: 'flex-start',
                    }}
                  >
                    <Text
                      style={{
                        fontSize: 15,
                        fontWeight: '600',
                        lineHeight: 15,
                        color: '#717171',
                        paddingBottom: 1,
                        textAlign: isRTL ? 'right' : 'left',
                      }}
                    >
                      {t('common.defaultPaymentMethod')}
                    </Text>
                    <View style={{
                      display: 'flex',
                      flexDirection: isRTL ? 'row-reverse' : 'row',
                      alignItems: 'center',
                      justifyContent: isRTL ? 'flex-end' : 'flex-start',
                      width: isRTL ? '70%' : 'auto',
                    }}
                    >
                      {renderListItemIcon(null, defaultCard)}
                      <Text
                        style={{
                          fontSize: 12,
                          fontWeight: '700',
                          lineHeight: 20,
                          paddingHorizontal: 5,
                          textAlign: isRTL ? 'right' : 'left',
                        }}
                      >
                        •••• •••• ••••
                      </Text>
                      <Text
                        style={{
                          fontSize: 12,
                          fontWeight: '700',
                          lineHeight: 20,
                          textAlign: isRTL ? 'right' : 'left',
                        }}
                      >
                        {`${
                          defaultCard && defaultCard.number
                            ? defaultCard.number.slice(-4)
                            : ''
                        }`}
                      </Text>
                    </View>
                  </View>
                  <View
                    style={{
                      width: '30%',
                    }}
                  >
                    <Button
                      onPress={showBottomSheetHandler}
                      size="small"
                      status="control"
                      style={styles.addCardButton}
                      accessoryLeft={() => (!isRTL ? (
                        Icon(
                          {
                            fill: '#1A0826',
                            width: 12,
                            height: 12,
                          },
                          'plus-outline',
                        )
                      ) : (
                        <></>
                      ))}
                      accessoryRight={() => (isRTL ? (
                        Icon(
                          {
                            fill: '#1A0826',
                            width: 12,
                            height: 12,
                          },
                          'plus-outline',
                        )
                      ) : (
                        <></>
                      ))}
                    >
                      {(evaProps) => (
                        <Text
                          {...evaProps}
                          style={{
                            fontSize: 12,
                            fontWeight: '700',
                            lineHeight: 18,
                            color: '#440099',
                            paddingLeft: !isRTL ? 6 : 0,
                            paddingRight: isRTL ? 6 : 0,
                            textAlign: isRTL ? 'right' : 'left',
                          }}
                        >
                          {t('common.addCard')}
                        </Text>
                      )}
                    </Button>
                  </View>
                </View>
              ) : (
                <View
                  style={{
                    display: 'flex',
                    flexDirection: 'row',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    justifyContent: 'space-between',
                  }}
                >
                  <View
                    style={{
                      display: 'flex',
                      flexDirection: 'column',
                      alignItems: 'flex-start',
                      flex: 1,
                    }}
                  >
                    <Text
                      style={{
                        fontSize: 15,
                        fontWeight: '500',
                        lineHeight: 15,
                        paddingBottom: 1,
                        textAlign: isRTL ? 'right' : 'left',
                      }}
                    >
                      {t('common.noDefaultPaymentMethod')}
                    </Text>
                    <Text
                      style={{
                        fontSize: 12,
                        fontWeight: '600',
                        lineHeight: 20,
                        color: '#717171',
                        marginRight: 5,
                        textAlign: isRTL ? 'right' : 'left',
                      }}
                    >
                      {t('common.clickToAddNewCard')}
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                  <View
                    style={{
                      width: '30%',
                    }}
                  >
                    <Button
                      onPress={showBottomSheetHandler}
                      size="small"
                      status="control"
                      style={styles.addCardButton}
                      accessoryLeft={() => (!isRTL ? (
                        Icon(
                          {
                            fill: '#1A0826',
                            width: 12,
                            height: 12,
                          },
                          'plus-outline',
                        )
                      ) : (
                        <></>
                      ))}
                      accessoryRight={() => (isRTL ? (
                        Icon(
                          {
                            fill: '#1A0826',
                            width: 12,
                            height: 12,
                          },
                          'plus-outline',
                        )
                      ) : (
                        <></>
                      ))}
                    >
                      {(evaProps) => (
                        <Text
                          {...evaProps}
                          style={{
                            fontSize: 12,
                            fontWeight: '700',
                            lineHeight: 18,
                            color: '#440099',
                            paddingLeft: !isRTL ? 6 : 0,
                            paddingRight: isRTL ? 6 : 0,
                            textAlign: isRTL ? 'right' : 'left',
                          }}
                        >
                          {t('common.addCard')}
                        </Text>
                      )}
                    </Button>
                  </View>
                </View>
              )}
            </Card>
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
      </Layout>
      <BottomSheetModal
        ref={bottomSheetRef}
        index={1}
        snapPoints={snapPoints}
        enablePanDownToClose
        backdropComponent={(backdropProps) => (
          <BottomSheetBackdrop {...backdropProps} enableTouchThrough />
        )}
      >
        <AddPaymentMethodBottomSheetContent
          showVgsForm={showVgsForm}
          setShowVgsForm={setShowVgsForm}
          bottomSheetRef={bottomSheetRef}
        />
      </BottomSheetModal>
    </>
  );
}

PaymentMethods.propTypes = {
  route: PropTypes.shape({
    params: PropTypes.shape({
      addCard: PropTypes.string,
    }),
  }),
  navigation: PropTypes.shape({
    navigate: PropTypes.func,
    goBack: PropTypes.func,
  }),
  showBottomSheetHandler: PropTypes.func,
};

PaymentMethods.defaultProps = {
  route: null,
  navigation: null,
  showBottomSheetHandler: () => {},
};

export default PaymentMethods;



AddPaymentMethodBottomSheetContent component:


/* eslint-disable no-multiple-empty-lines */
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { BackHandler, View } from 'react-native';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { Spinner } from '@ui-kitten/components';
import VgsPaymentForm from 'components/VgsPaymentForm';
import { fetchPaymentMethods } from 'reducers/paymentMethods';
import { resetRedirectData } from 'reducers/vgs';
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { t } from 'services/i18n';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import styles from './styles';

function AddPaymentMethodBottomSheetContent({
  navigation,
  bottomSheetRef,
  showVgsForm,
  setShowVgsForm,
}) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();


  useEffect(() => {
    const backAction = () => {
      bottomSheetRef.current.close();
      return true;
    };

    const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener(
      'hardwareBackPress',
      backAction,
    );

    return () => backHandler.remove();
  }, []);


  const handleBackFunction = () => {
    setShowVgsForm(false);
    dispatch(resetRedirectData());
    dispatch(fetchPaymentMethods());
    bottomSheetRef.current.close();
  };

  return (
    <ScrollView overScrollMode="never">
      <VgsPaymentForm
        handleBack={handleBackFunction}
        navigation={navigation}
        showHeader
      />
    </ScrollView>
  );
}

AddPaymentMethodBottomSheetContent.propTypes = {
  navigation: PropTypes.shape({
    navigate: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  }),
  bottomSheetRef: PropTypes.shape({
    current: PropTypes.shape({
      expand: PropTypes.func,
      close: PropTypes.func,
    }),
  }),
  showVgsForm: PropTypes.bool,
  setShowVgsForm: PropTypes.func,
};

AddPaymentMethodBottomSheetContent.defaultProps = {
  navigation: null,
  bottomSheetRef: null,
  showVgsForm: true,
  setShowVgsForm: () => {},
};

export default AddPaymentMethodBottomSheetContent;





Can you please provide a expo snack for the same ? so that i can provide a solution @devs1994

@ShailPatel sure, will do

@ShailPatel
Can you please check this code snippet? It isn't functioning correctly at the moment.
I just updated my codebase.
https://snack.expo.dev/@mirzahassan/26a265

@ShailPatel have you checked the codebase?

i am not able to run it
if i run it then only i'll be able to help please if you can make the code working and provide me then it will be best

@ShailPatelIt's a mobile application with a lot of files; I'm only sharing the logic relevant to the exact codebase. Can we connect on zoom or google meet? I run the app locally.

surely we connect but before that have few questions

The issue has occurred only in ios and not in android ?
If the issue has occurred only in ios then does your code works on other iPhone devices? or code is not working on all the iPhones?


https://www.linkedin.com/in/-shail-patel/
@devs1994 lets connect over linkedin
